# Azure MSAL authentication - SSO with MFA

Tags: azure, authentication, iframe, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I have an an iframe, which uses `MSAL` authentication. it's parent also uses the same auth mechanism and once the user has logged in the parent app, I should be able to log him in the iframe with `SSO`. I tried doing it with `loginHint` but I get this error:

[image: InteractionRequiredAuthError]

That's the piece of code in the iframe that receives the `loginHint` from the parent and trying to use it for `SSO`:

```
 window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  // check the origin of the data
  if (event.origin === parentDomain) {
    const loginHint = event.data;

    // attempt SSO
    publicClient
      .ssoSilent({
        scopes: ["openid", "profile", "User.Read"],
        loginHint,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
});
```

I think it might have something to do with the fact that my organization is using `MFA` (Multi factor authentication), but I'm not exactly sure. Is there a way to bypass this
without canceling the MFA?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use interactive login inside IFRAME with MSAL, also embedded webviews can stop working for security reassons authenticathing against third party providers like Google or others (OpenID).

It's not about MFA.

CmsiInterrupt - For security reasons, user confirmation is required for this request. Because this is an "interaction_required" error, the client should do interactive auth. This occurs because a system webview has been used to request a token for a native application - the user must be prompted to ask if this was actually the app they meant to sign into. To avoid this prompt, the redirect URI should be part of the following safe list:
http://
https://
msauth://(iOS only)
msauthv2://(iOS only)
chrome-extension:// (desktop Chrome browser only)

Comment: My redirect URI in this attempt is http://localhost, but I still get this error.

Comment: This error comes from AAD or B2C because your client cannot communicate securely with /authorize or /token endpoints.

Comment: And what can I do to solve this problem? It happens only when I try sso not regular login

Comment: Remove the IFRAME and rethink your client side code.

Comment: My goal is to allow access from my app to other apps in my organization, with both being able to also stand by themselves and provide service independently. That's why I went for Iframe. All under the same AAD and same tenant also. I'm looking for a way to auto log the user in the iframe, and though it should be possible since he already logged in the parent app. Isn't there any way to implement this? I'm open for changes just don't know what they must be.